# Namespace with extends or interface causes Fatal Error without autoloader

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

Why doesn't this work?

**web/index.php** (Not `web/src/App/App.php`)

```
<?php

namespace App;

// web/index.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new App();

class App extends \Silex\Application {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        echo 'Worked!';
    }
}
```

I also tried `namespace App {...}`, no change. It throws this exception:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'App\App' not found in /path/to/web/index2.php:8
Stack trace:
  #0 {main}
  thrown in /path/to/web/index2.php on line 8
```

As long as I remove the `extends ...` and the `parent` call part, it works. I also noticed `interface` does the same thing (trying to use `Serializable`). Is this an issue with the autoloader being confused? Is there a way to do this without putting the `App\App` class into a file in `src\App\App.php`?

**Note:** this is an exercise to build a single-file application with Silex, so "just put it in a file" isn't an answer. I want to know why this doesn't work, which has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The problem in your code is,***

In namespace, You are initiating class object before it being declared and  loaded. In your above code you are doing same thing,

**1.** You are initiating `App` class object which lies in `App` namespace

**2.** You are initiating class object at the moment class when is not yet declared(As it is defined below in your code).

In your above code, not even your loader be called. It will be called if you initiate `App\App` class object after its declaration. and If your loader does not work fine then afterwards you will possibly get this error.

> Fatal Error: **Silex\Application** class not found

***Please checkout some examples and findings.***

[**Example 1**](https://eval.in/776891) Here loader is expected to be called but not called, because you have registered after initialization of class(`$app = new App();`).

[**Example 2**](https://eval.in/776893) Here, calling class will look for autoloading class because here initialization takes place after registration of loader and declaration of class, which is probably answers your question.

**Change your code with this to get it fix:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

class App extends \Silex\Application {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        echo 'Worked!';
    }
}

$app = new App();
```

Comment: Huh. Why would declaring the `$app` variable before the class definition make a difference? Shouldn't the class be hoisted?

Comment: Also, no error, it works fine; I'm using `use Silex\Application;`.

Comment: When ever you use `$app = new App();`  it will first find all its extending classes and then will first call constructor and from there your parent class constructor will be called.

Comment: That doesn't explain why where it's instantiated should matter. This seems like a bug.

Comment: Your code starting working might be a case, when you initialized the object at that moment you class not yet defined. If you are doing initialization of class before it is declared in namespace.

Comment: That's what I'm saying though, it should have been hoisted during compile time. This looks like it's hoisting it first from the other namespace and not `App`.

Comment: Yes, exactly this i am trying to say. You completed my sentence